# Windows Device Recovery Tool 3.1.5 Proxy Issue

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile, networking, recovery-tool

I am trying to rollback from Windows 10 to Windows 8.1 on my Lumia 1020 using the Windows Device Recovery Tool, but I'm receiving an error message once I click "Install Software" and agree to the warnings/disclaimers:

[image]

I have followed all instructions on verifying proxy settings on my computer and on my phone, tried using different internet connections, running the recovery tool on a different OS, resetting the phone to factory settings, removing the SIM card, but the error is always the same.

Here is my phone information, if it helps:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/10070/106

Answer (score 2):

I found the Nokia Software Updater for Retail (Version 4.3.2) to be a good alternative in case the Windows Device Recovery Tool does not work as intended (obviously for Nokia phones only).

[You can download the tool here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5g4iqpbelwwpu6e/NokiaSoftwareUpdaterForRetail_4.3.2.exe), the restore process is fairly straightforward.

As for your specific issue, it seems this is a problem on Microsofts side as you have eliminated all the variables - perhaps a corrupted ROM? Try contacting Microsoft directly if the issue persists.

Comment: Just installed it and tried it, but it doesn't support Lumia 1020, just like Nokia Software Recovery Tool. I've tried Microsoft's Support, but they keep giving me silly instructions like creating an additional user on my computer and performing a clean boot, even though I have used computers with different Operating Systems.